# How to get position coordinates of QGraphicWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a moveable label inside a `QGraphicsWidget` that is inside a `QGraphicsScene` like so

```
QLabel *SelectLabel = new QLabel("Select This");

QGraphicsWidget* ParentWidget = new QGraphicsWidget();
ParentWidget->setFlags (QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);

GraphicsScene->addItem(ParentWidget);


QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = MainScene->addWidget(SelectLabel);
proxy->setParentItem(ParentWidget);
```

This allows me to move (hold down left mouse button and drag) the label freely inside of the QGraphicsArea. However, I need a way of knowing exactly when and where the label/QGraphicsWidget is being moved. After searching I found the `QGraphicsItem::ItemPositionChange` flag and tried setting it in `->setFlag()` and applying the slot like this:

```
connect(ParentWidget, SIGNAL(moveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMoveEvent*)),
             this,    SLOT(labelPositionChange()));
```

But then I get the error:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal 
QGraphicsWidget::moveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMoveEvent*)
```

So, can someone show me how I can get the move events for my `QGraphicsWidget`? Thanks.

Comment: moveEvent is not a signal.

Comment: So what would the signal be that has that effect?

Comment: You could subclass QGraphicsWidget() and emit a signal in you subclass when moveEvent() is called. However I am really not familiar with this class maybe there is a better way that does not involve subclassing QGraphicsWidget

Comment: @drescherjm - I'm starting to subclass and will post the code but can you elaborate on what exactly I am subclassing?

Comment: OK I think I see how to subclass the moveEvent(), this looks to be the best solution so far...

Comment: He is talking about: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsobject.html#xChanged

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't really help though as I need both x & y and looks like the way to get that is by subclassing moveEvent().

Answer (score 1):

The `moveEvent` is not a signal. It's an event handler, meant to be reimplemented in a derived class. Alas, there are signals you want: `QGraphicsObject::xChanged` and `QGraphicsObject::yChanged`.

In the complete example below, a text item is used to display the position. The scene alignment and rectangle are set so that the scene doesn't move in relation to the view, and thus the text stays fixed in the view.

[image: screenshot]

```
// https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/questions/graphics-widget-move-signals-51680570
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   QGraphicsScene scene;
   QGraphicsView view(&scene);
   view.setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);
   scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 1, 1);

   QGraphicsWidget parent;
   parent.setPos(150, 100);
   QLabel label("Select This");
   label.setContentsMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
   auto *proxy = scene.addWidget(&label);
   proxy->setParentItem(&parent);
   parent.setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable);
   scene.addItem(&parent);

   QGraphicsTextItem text;
   scene.addItem(&text);
   auto const updateText = [&] {
      text.setPlainText(QString("%1, %2").arg(parent.x()).arg(parent.y()));
   };
   QObject::connect(&parent, &QGraphicsObject::xChanged, &text, updateText);
   QObject::connect(&parent, &QGraphicsObject::yChanged, &text, updateText);
   updateText();

   view.setMinimumSize(320, 320);
   view.show();
   return a.exec();
}
```